# Searching post by date on the wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My plan is to make a Date search form, but i need to query the post date while searching because for example if i search august 13 it will show nothing,

How can i search the post date of the post

Im Using this code but nothing happens i tried reading this article https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/, im very sorry im new on wordpress and php, and learning thank you,. I think this is wrong

```
        <?php
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => 12, 
        'year'  => $current_year,
        'monthnum' => $current_month,
        'order'    => 'ASC' ) );
        query_posts( $args );        
        $x = 0;
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

and this is my ordinary search

```
            <?php
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => 12 ) );
        query_posts( $args );        
        $x = 0;
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like:

```
<?php
$year = '1365';
$month = '03';
$day = '30';
$search_date = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&monthnum=' . $month . '&day=' . $day );
if($search_date->have_posts()) : while ($search_date->have_posts()) : $search_date->the_post();?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
         <?php the_title(); ?>
   </a>
   <br/>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This will show a simple list of title with links of the posts from 1365.03.30